# URL route configuration cannot deal with periods in url

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a mvc controller that is linked to a model file that was created with the ADO.NET wizard. The id column isn't filled with some normal values like integers or even GUIDs, but strings that can have periods. The auto generated edit functionality gets screwed over because the route engine takes the character in the id as configuration and throws an exception:

`The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

the edit action is formated as:

```
// GET: .../Edit/5
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
{
//my code
}
```

and when the url doesn't contain any spec character (ie: `/Edit/2982-4-112A`) then everything works wonderfully, but when it contains periods (ie: `/Edit/125-2-10.5`) the exception follows.

i have tried adding the `web.config` line

`<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />`

didn't solve the problem.

how does one work around this?

I feel like I could intercept the parameter and exchange the dot for something else until it gets to the method at which point I revert the change. Don't know how to do that though.

Comment: And what is the exception message??

Comment: the one i wrote above `The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`, it is a 404

Comment: It does not relate to any entity

Comment: Oh, maybe i phrased my self wrong, its not a but in the Entity Framework but rather a problem with MVC Routing configuration because of the id column content format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment my solution is this:

at the place where the links need to be generated i do a `String.Replace('.','|')` and then again once the action is called `String.Replace('|','.')`.

still think there's a better way though.